# R - using shinytest with rhandsontable when table uses hot_validate_*

Tags: r, shiny, automated-tests, phantomjs, rhandsontable

I am trying to create automated tests for a shiny app that uses rhandsontable. The rhandsontable uses hot_validate_numeric functions, and when running the app via shinytest, the rhandsontable does not render (when I try taking a screenshot of the running app), and if I call any computation in the app that depends on said rhot table, the app crashes.

A simple reproducible example where I display `mtcars` as a rhot table, and a button that computes mean of mpg using the data from the rhot table.

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test"),
    fluidRow(column(12, rHandsontableOutput("input_table"))), 
    actionButton("button", "Compute MPG Mean"), 
    textOutput("mean")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$input_table <- renderRHandsontable(
        rhandsontable(mtcars) %>% hot_validate_numeric("mpg", min = 0, max = 40)
    )
    observeEvent(
        input$button, {
            n = mean(hot_to_r(input$input_table)$mpg)
            output$mean = renderText(n)
        }
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now if I run the tests in the following manner, the app crashes:

```r
app <- ShinyDriver$new("path/to/app")
app$takeScreenshot() # rhot table does not appear in this

app$setInputs(button = "click")
# I get a message saying : Server did not update any output value within 3 seconds
# And if take another screenshot of app, I can see the app has crashed.
```

The app works normally, it only fails when using shinytest. If I remove hot_validate_numeric, then shinytest works too.

Is there some way I can use hot_validate_numeric and still be able to run tests?

Comment: looking at the code of hot_validate_numeric, it seems to create javascript function for validation. So the issue might be that javascript code does not get executed automatically when running through the web driver and hence the table fails to render?